# Module not found in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I know there are several posts about this but I couldn't quite understand.

I have the following project structure:

```
engine
--alpha-api
----app.py
----__init__.py
--api_utils
----utils.py
----__init__.py
--beta_api
```

and I have the following Dockefile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN pip install -r ./alpha-api/requirements.txt --target ./alpha-api
```

The Dockerfile is under the alpha-api. That cannot be changed since I have two different lambdas in the same repo.
When I run docker build with the context of the engine directory I do maintain the context and get the same project structure. (`docker build -f ./alpha-api/Dockerfile -t alpha-api .` )

However, when i run a container and call ./alpha-api/app.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from api_utils.utils import DateStringFormat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api_utils'
```

Do you know why it doesn't recognize api_utils?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `python ./alpha-api/app.py`, Python will only have all files within `./alpha-api` in its path.

Setting your `PYTHONPATH` to `./` (or `${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}`) prior to running the file could help.

Answer (score 1):

In order for python python to understand that a folder is actually a python module, it must contain a `__init__.py` file. Try adding an empty `__init__.py` to your api_utils folder.

Comment: It has one actually. I will edit the project structure